# Installing Allegro 5

Tags: installation, allegro5

Can someone please walk me through installing Allegro 5 or guide me in a direction to go to who can show me how to install it?

I did a little googling, researching on how to configure my security settings, so I believe I was allowed to copy over the lib, bin, and include folders over into vc: lib, bin, and include folders. But, now I am struggling with copying over the bin folder into my sysWOW64 in 7:29 of the video.

I cannot seem to solve the access denied message for the life of me. I am using a Windows 10 64 bit operating system along with visual studio 2015. And to solve my Allegro 5 installation problems, I have referenced the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ2krJ8Ls2A to install allegro5.

I really want to start game programming. But the biggest challenge is: by- passing my computers security to grant me access to install the Allegro 5 bin items into my `sysWOW64` folder.

Comment: You don't have to install it at sysWOW64... Let me look around to see if I find a guide for you, but it is mostly configuring the project settings directly on Visual Studio

Comment: Okay thank you, that will be greatly appreciative!

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using VS2015, and will be using Allegro 5 from the precompiled binaries (as opossed to building from source), and want to prepare the environment to use the library right?

Comment: That is correct i'm using vs2015. As far as using allegro 5 from the precompiled binaries (I have no idea what that means), however that is right, I am trying to use allegro5 libraries. I am working on building a little action game on allegro5. I read in another forum that this was a good beginning library to get started on game development in c++.

Comment: Precompiled binaries means that you have a program/library ready to be fed to the CPU as opossed to having the source code of the program/library and having to compile it yourselve Somebody did that for you so that you only focus on using Allegro to make something and not in how to build  Allegro. Indeed it is a nice lib for beginners :)

Comment: Okay, so I've tested and ran the allegro5 source code you provided. And in return it gave me an error message. How do I copy the whole error message

Comment: Hmm interesting, I was thinking the guide had no error. Try right clicking the error window and selecting copy.

Comment: got it I hit shift and clicked, that allowed me to copy the entire error message.  And keep in mind I followed the original video I posted a link to called code made easy. So I tweaked around with my security settings. That might have cause a problem. Stack overflow is saying the message is too long to comment.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error TRK0005 Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. flipHeadGame C:\Users\jonathon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\TRACKER 1
This looks like the main issue, the rest just seems like it may be due to a syntax error, but I did copy and paste the code you provided.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  cannot open source file "allegro5\allegro5.h" flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 1
Error (active)  identifier "al_init" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 5
Error (active)  identifier "ALLEGRO_DISPLAY" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 7

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  identifier "display" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 7
Error (active)  identifier "al_set_app_name" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 8
Error (active)  identifier "al_create_display" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 9

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  namespace "std" has no member "cerr" flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 12
Error (active)  namespace "std" has no member "endl" flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 12
Error (active)  identifier "al_rest" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 13

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  identifier "al_clear_to_color" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 17
Error (active)  identifier "al_map_rgb" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 17
Error (active)  identifier "al_flip_display" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 18

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  identifier "al_rest" is undefined flipHeadGame c:\Users\jonathon\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame.cpp 19
Error TRK0005 Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. flipHeadGame C:\Users\jonathon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\flipHeadGame\flipHeadGame\TRACKER 1

Comment: Ok so CL looks like an internal Visual Studio program, probably something got deleted or changed while you tried to make the changes to the sysWOW64 and other system libraries. Without the full error message I'm not sure what is the cause... Anyways gotta go its 1 hour past midnight here. Try looking on Google how to post a gist (spelled like that "gist") and post the link here of the gist containing full error mesaage

Comment: OK that will do also xD, I edited the code at the end of my answer, paste it again in visual studio to see if it works.

Comment: With the added #include <iostream>. This error message went away "Severity Code Description Project File Line Error TRK0005 Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. flipHeadGame C:\Users\jonathon\documents\visual studio

Comment: But this error came up "Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error MSB4175 The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\jonathon\AppData\Local\Temp\5jm40uu1.dll' because it is being used by another process. flipHeadGame C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets 214
" i've gotten this task factory error before. It's a common problem.

Comment: And the edited allegro code made the error message  on the include go away. This worked: #include "allegro5\allegro5.h". It's not underlined red anymore.

Comment: Honestly speaking, what a strange list of error you have there... At least I shot one of them down. Tomorrow I'll take a closer look at those and update the answer accordingly. BTW, as soon as you get enough rep put the comments on the answer not here to limit the scope of my solution there and this space for other people suggestions and comments

Comment: Never mind I spoke to soon. I debugged it and #include "allegro5\allegro5.h" this was underlined red. Should I reinstall Microsoft visual studio 2015 and attempt this guide again? I did not modify my sysWOW64 folder. I wasn't modify it my security prevented me making any changes to that folder. The only folders that were modified were the visual studio vc folders.

Comment: Any other piece underlined in red? Close any other instance of Vsiauk Studio you may have open

Comment: That would probably solve the errors. As they are quite different from the usual code related ones. It seems the compiler got broken somehow

Comment: The entire code is red except for a very brief part. The parts that aren't red are if statements, nullptr, and the return 0.

Comment: Okay i'll have to do that tomorrow it's late over here as well.

Comment: OK I'll look at it tomorrow, try to repair VS2015 using the installer to be sure the environment is not broken

Comment: I tried repairing and uninstalling visual studio. But visual studio just sat their like it was trying to load. And than after awhile asked,"Would you like to cancel set up". If I clicked, "No" it would repeat what it just did. Right now i'm trying to get ccleaner installed on my computer so it can clean some stuff up for me. But I cannot install it because when I referenced the original video I posted. I must have adjusted something in my security settings which has been making my computer act different. I'm running windows 10.

Comment: I'm trying to find a security video that'll give me complete control so I can reset the security values to their default state. The pc costed $1,500 and I purchased all the parts over the summer and assembled it myself. I've been having a lot of issues with it lately. A lot of pausing up and crashing. I believe it's either the motherboard, ssd, or more likely the operating system. I honestly think it's the operating system. The computers brand new and everything within is brand new as well. Last night it was extremely slow and windows10 wouldn't let me click on anything.

Comment: After an hour of working with it I had to to turn it off for 20 minutes and that fixed the issue. It just froze up and wouldn't let me click anything. That's why i'm working on downloaded ccleaner so I can clean out the clutter. And than hopefully I can proceed back to getting allegro5 working.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFZsXI9sq34 I used this video to mess around with my security settings. As of right now I don't really have access to anything on my computer and I cannot do anything. At 0:57 I decided to remove everything on the list so now I cannot see those items. I couldn't find the disable inheritance button on windows 10. And when I did check mark, replace all child access, it gave me an error. I'm thinking about wiping my solid state drive and hoping that'll fix my security settings. And i'll just start over from scratch.

Comment: I don't really know what else to do right now.

Comment: Wow this issue escalated quickly.... Do as you must to have a clean environment, then install Visual Studio again, sorry to hear you need to do that. Now a quick question, why is it that file access got screwed up so much there.... Don't do that again xD Good Luck!

Comment: Try asking a question at Super User Stack exchange about doing a clean install of windows 10 is you don't know how to make it, it has all the tools included but it is not that obvious. Keep in mind personal files might be lost in the process

Comment: Are there any windows 10 security forums I could post on? Doing a clean reinstall is easy. This will be my second time. And thank you so much for the help! I messed around with the security settings to install those three folders in the video. And after that everything just went down hill. I kept watching videos to try and fix my security settings but only to find they were only getting more and more ruined. I really don't want to have to do a clean install. I"m saving that for a last resort kind of option. A restore point would be nice.

Comment: Well you can try asking at SuperUser here at stack exchange, they handle that sort of stuff, StackOverflow is only about programming

Comment: I'm attempting to install it on my laptop now while my desktop getting repaired. I'm using visual studio 2013 and i'm running a windows 64 bit system. I still get the error "Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'allegro5\allegro5.h': No such file or directory c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\allegrotest\allegrotest\allegrotest.cpp 5 1 allegroTest" Every other error just seems to be a syntax error due to that main error.

Comment: In a trial to fix the error. I moved my extracted allegro files from my desktop to my program files on the hard drive.

Comment: ok so that error happens because the path you typed in step 3.2 is not the same one that the files are installed to. It has to be the exact same path. Use the suggestion I made on step 2. Copy the files to the topmost folder of your harddisk, the one where all other folders go. That is the root. On another note, it is not recommended to manually edit files on program files, that can easily break this other system as well.

Comment: in instruction 3.2. I copied "C:\allegro\include\" and pasted that there where the instructions told me. Do I need to head into the bin folder and grab it from there?

Comment: in instruction 3.2 and any instructions similar I copied "C:\allegro\include\" or what it stated for me to copy and I pasted that there where the instructions told me. Do I need to head into the include folder and grab it from there? I also moved my allegro folder from computer/local disk c/ programs to just computer/local C disc. And I pasted it there.

Comment: I think it might be sensing allegro 5 now. But i'm not sure it's giving this error message now "Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__al_rest referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\Jon\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\allegroTest\allegroTest\allegroTest.obj allegroTest
" And nothing is underlined red before the entire code I had copied to test allegro was underlined red. I don't really know what fixed the no directory error. All I did was move my allegro 5 folder out of programs to just computer -> local disk c. And I let my computer sit around for awhile.

Comment: Interesting error... When you created this project in Visual Studio, it was a Console Application/Windows Application… and you choose blank project/precompiled headers? Maybe it is trying to find the wrong main function. As in winMain(no idea what goes here)  instead of main(int argc, char** argV)

Answer (score 3):

OK so all the guides on the net seem to be outdated or seem to forget that the [Official Site](http://liballeg.org) has recent and modern binaries ready for download. So here is how to setup Allegro:

### Assumptions

First thing first, I will be using the **Unstable** branch, 5.1, since it is the one that has the new binaries. And Second, I will be using Visual Studio 2013 but it should be exactly the same for Visual Studio 2015 (Step 1 below has the only difference in the process you might encounter).

### Step 1

We will download Allegro 5 direct from the [Gna!](http://download.gna.org/allegro/allegro-unstable-bin/5.1.12/) repository. Here you select the file depending on what you have and what you want to do.

This directory has 4 files, in my case, I will download **allegro-msvc2013-x86-5.1.12.zip** and you will download **allegro-msvc2015-x86-5.1.12.zip**. Select the x64 version only if you know what you are doing.

### Step 2

When it finishes downloading, extract the contents somewhere that is easy to reach and that you will not move, such as the **root of your hardrive** or inside **Documents**. I'll go with the root, usually drive `C:`. After the extraction, you should have a folder in `C:\allegro\` with the following content:

```
allegro\
 |-bin\
 |-include\
 |-lib\
```

It is important you remember where you extracted the files as setting the environment correctly depends on its ability to locate this path.

### Step 3

[image: Example Property Dialog on Visual Studio 2013]

Here we tell Visual Studio how to use Allegro. Open Visual Studio and create a new C++project/open the project you want Allegro to be used in. With the project open, right click its name on the solution explorer and open **Properties** then:

1. At the top, where it says something like *Configuration: Active(Debug)*, select *All Configurations*.
2. On the left menu select **C/C++ -> General**. On this configuration page, select *Additional Include Directories* and edit it to contain`C:\allegro\include\` in its text field.
3. On the left menu select **Linker -> General**. On this configuration page, select *Additional Library Directories* and edit it to contain `C:\allegro\lib\` in its text field.
4. Click on Apply at the bottom, but don´t close the window yet.
5. Back at the top, select the Debug configuration.
6. On the left menu select **Linker -> Input**. On this configuration page, select *Additional Dependencies* and edit it to contain `allegro_monolith-debug.lib` in its text field.
7. (Optional)On the left menu select **Linker -> System**. On this configuration page, select *SubSystem* and change it to Console from the drop-down box. This will give you a working terminal window in Debug mode to which you can write ...err... debug stuff ;)
8. Click on Apply at the bottom, but don´t close the window yet.
9. Back at the top, select the Release configuration.
10. On the left menu select **Linker -> Input**. On this configuration page, select *Additional Dependencies* and edit it to contain `allegro_monolith.lib` in its text field.
11. (Optional)On the left menu select **Linker -> System**. On this configuration page, select *SubSystem* and change it to Windows from the drop-down box. This will prevent the Terminal window to appear on Release versions of your program.
12. Click on Apply then OK, this will close the Property Pages of the project and should prepare it for Allegro.

### Step 4

This is the part where we test everything worked...(or not, see next step after error)

Create a *.cpp file or use the one where your main function is located and change it to this small test program: (I give away all my rights to it and place it under public domain)

```
#include "allegro5\allegro5.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    al_init();

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = nullptr;
    al_set_app_name("Hello World from Allegro 5.1!");
    display = al_create_display(640, 480);
    if (display == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Well, something is not working..." << std::endl;
        al_rest(5.0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(5.0);
    return 0;
}
```

If after compiling and running you get a blank window that closes in 5 seconds then Allegro is ready! If not, post your error message and I'll take a look at what happened.

### Step 5

Where we solve the missing DLL error upon execution...

So the program should have compiled correctly and Visual Studio will now attemp to run it. Upon starting, the following might appear:

[image: Error: The program cannot start because a DLL is missing in the system.]

The solution is to copy on the Debug folder on the root of your project the `allegro_monolith-debug-5.1.dll` file, so that it is located beside your program's .exe file. Similarly, on the Release folder you have to copy `allegro_monolith-5.1.dll` beside that folder's executable. Both of this files should be on the `allegro\bin\` directory of the downloaded archive. Keep in mind that you would probably need another dll from the ones I said, but it should also be included on the file you downloaded from *Gna!*.

Comment: Note that I might have forgotten to include the Allegro [dependencies](http://download.gna.org/allegro/allegro-deps/1.2.0/) installation instructions here... but maybe they are not needed anymore, waiting for confirmation on [this thread](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/615781)